# Как получить имя файла, в который импортирован модуль?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, модули

Есть 2 файла, prog.py и module.py
Содержимое prog.py:

```
import module
```

Содержимое module.py:

```
print(__file__)
```

И дело в том, что при запуске prog.py вывод будет `module`, а не `prog`, как можно это "починить"? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Никак, потому что один и тот же модуль может быть импортирован в несколько разных файлов

Comment: Когда у меня много всяких импортов, я закидываю в каждый файл такую строчку: `print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<25} | __package__={2:<25}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__))) ` и таким образом каждый файл напишет информацию о себе(когда будет подключён).

Comment: @andreymal не в этом дело, запускается не сам модуль, а программа, в которой он импортирован

Comment: @Zailox это никак не отменяет того факта, что один и тот же модуль может быть импортирован в несколько разных файлов — даже внутри одной и той же программы

Comment: @andreymal жалко, я хотел сделать что-то на подобии pyarmor, но с файлом ключа заместо папки

Comment: Не очень понятно как это связано с данным вопросом, тот же pyarmor передаёт имя текущего файла в свой модуль напрямую без всякой магии

Comment: @andreymal как это без всякой магии? Решение, кстати, нашёл

Comment: @Zailox ну вот прямо в документации pyarmor написан пример `__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x28\x83\x20\x58....')` — самый обычный вызов функции, в которую файл передаёт своё собственное имя. Не очень понятно, что вам мешает сделать так же, например

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, просто хотелось код сделать более чистым, чтобы писать просто *import module* и шифрованный код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306091/python-how-to-get-a-running-scripts-file-name-in-import-package)
Нужно использовать sys.argv

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Совсем не факт, что название запущенного файла будет совпадать с названием того файла, который импортирует модуль. Представьте, что программа импортирует модуль `foo`, а `foo` импортирует модуль `module` — в `sys.argv[0]` будет вовсе не `foo`

Comment: @andreymal пока что я импортирую только модули наподобии time, random и т.п., поэтому сейчас проблем быть не должно

Comment: И всё же в общем случае на тот вопрос, который задан на данный момент, этот ответ является неверным, поскольку sys.argv не имеет никакого отношения к импортам модулей

Comment: (а при запуске через интерактивную консоль это будет вообще пустая строка)

Comment: @andreymal в данном случае нет другого решения, которое не задействует программу

Answer (score 0):

```
   file-prog

    import modl
    modl.f()
    print(__file__)
```

---

```
   file-modl

   def f():
    print (__file__)

   if __name__=='main':
       pass
```

---

Запускаем Prog

```
path\modl.py
path\prog.py
```

Или я вопрос нее так понял

Comment: Не совсем, допустим код *prog.py* такой:

```
import module

```

А код *module.py* такой:

```
a = __file__ ; a = open(a, "r")

```

И дело в том, что при запуске prog.py переменная а будет равна module.py,  а не prog.py

Comment: Можете передать любой аргумент в функции.